# Check if local branch does already exist remote

Tags: git, bash, branch

I have a local branch with name `${VERSION}-SNAP` where `$VERSION` is an environment variable.

```
VERSION="1.0.O"
```

Now I'm searching for an efficient way to check if this branch does already exist remote.

I was thinking in this direction but it did not work:

```
for each ${VERSION}-SNAP | `git branch -r` do;
  echo "branch does exist, exit.."
  exit 1;
done;
```

Comment: What is `for each ${VERSION}-SNAP` supposed to do? Nothing here changes the value of `$VERSION`. What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: Technically, this approach can fall victim to a race condition. Just because the branch doesn't exist when you first check doesn't mean it won't exist when you try to do whatever depends on it not existing.

Comment: @Chris it just contains some number

Comment: @chepner what is a better approach? I just need a way to check if my local branch exists remotely. The way I'm doing it in bash doesn't matter.

Comment: How do you define "exist remotely"? Based on branch name (which might be completely unrelated from a development perspective)? By commit hashes? Again, _what are you trying to accomplish by doing this_?

Comment: @Chris sorry I don't know what's so difficult to understand.. Just compare if the name of a local branch already exists in the remote repository..

Comment: @DenCowboy, because I can't envision any possible use of comparing local and remote branch names. Branch names are almost meaningless. I'm asking you _why_ you are trying to do this. Once you determine whether a branch with a similar name exists remotely, what will you do with the answer? Git might provide a much better way of accomplishing whatever you're trying to do by looking at branch names. Please read about the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). It is very likely that you have one.

Answer (score 0):

```
git ls-remote -h <url_of_remote_repository> <branch>
```

The command tells if the branch exists in the remote repository, and which commit it points to if it exists.